# Google Drive API Deny sharing of file for an user who has 'writer' permission of that file

Tags: java, permissions, google-drive-api

I want to deny sharing of a file by an user who has "writer" permission on the same file in Google Drive.

PS: I do not want to modify the permission to "Reader"

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue using the following code:

```
File body = new File();
//check the user email if needed
body.setWritersCanShare(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Users with [edit](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494886?hl=en) permissions have access to

- View files and folders
- Download or sync files to another device
- Make a copy of files to save in Google Drive
- Comment and suggest edits in files
- Edit documents, spreadsheets, presentations, and drawings
- **Share or unshare files with others**
- Add or remove files from a folder
- Upload and delete file versions

If you don't want them to share it you have to change there permissions to either can view or can comment.   There is no way to change that [documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494886?hl=en). there is no work around.  Users with write permissions have access to share as well.